# gridView builder with dynamic Filter (search)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi guys I have a list of categories and what I'm trying to do is search for a category by it's name and display the matched category inside the same view :

[![when I want to search for a service(carpentry) only the one in yellow will be displayed][2]][2]

The problem is now I can't type a text inside that searchfield and when I remove the function onChanged everything goes back to normal and I can type text again

this is my code :

```
class _HomeScreen00State extends State<HomeScreen00> {
  Category category = new Category();
  List myIds = [];
  List myServiceNames = [];
  List myImagesUrl = [];
  bool isLogin;
  List<Category> _searchResult = [];
  TextEditingController controllerSearchField = new TextEditingController();
  List<Category> _categoryDetails = [];

 onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
   _searchResult.clear();
     if (text.isEmpty) {
     setState(() {});
      return;
     }

_categoryDetails.forEach((_categoryDetail) {
  if (_categoryDetail.name.contains(text) )
    _searchResult.add(_categoryDetail);
});

setState(() {});
 }



   @override
   void initState() {
    // Calling API using Bloc
    super.initState();
    fetchAlbum();
   
       }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   TextEditingController controllerSearchField = new TextEditingController();

   return Scaffold(
     appBar: PreferredSize(
       preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(83),
      child: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: AppColors.white,
        height: 83,
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 65,
                width: 350,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: controllerSearchField,
                    onChanged:(value) => onSearchTextChanged(value),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: AppColors.white,
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: AppColors.white,
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Pesquisar por serviço...',

                      fillColor: AppColors.grey2,
                      filled: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(08),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
                        color: AppColors.white,
                        onPressed: () {
                          controllerSearchField.clear();
                          onSearchTextChanged('');
                        },
                      )),

                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: test() as Widget,
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.9, -0.35),
        child: Text(
          'Serviços',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.blackCupons,
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      _searchResult.length != 0 || controllerSearchField.text.isNotEmpty
      ?Positioned.fill(
        top: 180,
        child: GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 12, crossAxisSpacing: 12),
          itemCount: _searchResult.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final Widget image = Material(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: Image.network(
                ApiConstants.BASE_URL + _searchResult[index].imageUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            );

            final Widget name = FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
              child: Text(_searchResult[index].name),
            );

            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                print("card id : " + myIds[index].toString());
                isLogin = await FlutterSession().get("isLogin");
                if (isLogin == false || isLogin == null) {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ProfissionaisList(),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: GridTile(
                footer: Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(4)),
                  ),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  child: GridTileBar(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.grey3,
                    title: name,
                  ),
                ),
                child: image,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ):
      Positioned.fill(
        top: 180,
        child: GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 12, crossAxisSpacing: 12),
          itemCount: myImagesUrl.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final Widget image = Material(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: Image.network(
                ApiConstants.BASE_URL + myImagesUrl[index],
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            );

            final Widget name = FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
              child: Text(myServiceNames[index]),
            );

            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                print("card id : " + myIds[index].toString());
                isLogin = await FlutterSession().get("isLogin");
                if (isLogin == false || isLogin == null) {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ProfissionaisList(),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: GridTile(
                footer: Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(4)),
                  ),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  child: GridTileBar(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.grey3,
                    title: name,
                  ),
                ),
                child: image,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
 }

 }
```

I removed the API consumption code and some session verification if you need full code I can update it any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because of the `setState()` which is called at every character inserted.

The best way to handle a search like this is to use a debouncer to give the query a delay, like this:

```dart
  Timer? timer;

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    timer?.cancel();

    timer = Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      () {
        _searchResult.clear();
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          setState(() {});
          return;
        }

        _categoryDetails.forEach((_categoryDetail) {
          if (_categoryDetail.name.contains(text))
            _searchResult.add(_categoryDetail);
        });

        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }
```

If you handle your input like this, at every character inserted you will close the old timer and instantiate a new one with a 250ms delay, so if the users stops typing it will run your search callback.